# Keycloak Service Provider Metadata and IdP metadata

Tags: docker, keycloak, amazon-ecs

"Hello everyone, I'm currently working on a project that involves implementing an Identity Broker mechanism with Keycloak for AWS Connect, allowing users to log in using a SAML 2.0 Identity Provider (IdP). For this project, I'm using AWS Fargate with ECS (Elastic Container Service).

Here's the scenario: I've created a task definition that utilizes a previously defined ECR (Elastic Container Registry) image, and I've set up a service that runs the task. Everything is functioning as expected. However, I've encountered an issue when ECS Fargate scales up to start a new task.

The problem is that the Service Provider Metadata and IdP metadata of the new container differ from the XML of the previous container. This means that the user can't login into aws because there is this error
[SAML ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVrWr.png)

I have two questions regarding this:

- Is there a way to initiate a Docker container that retains its
  previous state when scaling up in ECS Fargate, or does ECS solely
  rely on the 'docker run' command to start containers?
- Is there a method to customize and manipulate the SAML Service
  Provider Metadata and IdP Metadata in Keycloak, ensuring the same
  KeyName and X.509 Certificate are used consistently?

I hope this clarifies my inquiry, and I appreciate your assistance."

Comment: Can you perhaps describe your cluster's configuration in more detail? For example, what is the database configuration? Are you following this guide? https://aws-samples.github.io/keycloak-on-aws/en/

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm using the h2 default one db and I'm not following that guide.

Comment: I have a ecs cluster with fargate as explained, with a service that use a keycloak container (defined with a task definition). From this task can be started other tasks for scaling purposes, but every task is different (from metadata.xml side) than the other one even if I had imported the realm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the state outside of the container. Right now you are using the embedded H2 database which runs inside the same container as KeyCloak. This means each new container (each ECS Fargate Task) gets a new database. The state, which is stored in the database, is not being shared across containers.

You really can't use the H2 embedded database when running KeyCloak on ECS Fargate. There's no way to make that work correctly. You will have to switch to using a database external to your ECS tasks, such as an AWS RDS or Aurora database, like they recommend in [this guide](https://aws-samples.github.io/keycloak-on-aws/en/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I understand tight, everything related to Keycloak config (realm, metadata ,roles and ecc) Will be stored on db and used by all the new task started from ECS fargate?

Comment: I believe that's right, but I'm not a Keycloak expert. I just spent some time looking at the Keycloak docker image documentation. I do know for an absolute fact that you can't use an embedded database like H2 in your Fargate containers like you are right now and expect that to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with RDS db. My other idea Is to do a docker commit of my running container and create a new image for the Fargate containers with the state of the First One task. Maybe in this case I will have all the stuffs needed

Comment: You would have to do a docker commit every time you make a change, like adding a new user account or something. And you can't do `docker commit` from inside Fargate anyway.

Comment: Yes, I have done exactly this but from an ec2. I have taken the snapshot of docker container with docker commit command and created an image that I have pushed on ECR. When I have launched two task they had the same configuration

Comment: Yes I get that you can do that by creating the image somewhere else, but it's a terrible way to manage changes to your app, and the fact remains that each instance would be talking to their own isolated database, instead of a shared database, which is simply the wrong way to run Keycloak in a distributed/scaled environment.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I don't know if with RDS cluster They can share also the metadata.xml. For my purposes I don't Need a shared db because the user with their credential are stored in LDAP providers. For give you an idea the user come from NAM/IdP--> insert their credentials to login into a portal, from this portal there Is my Keycloak proxy link that Will create an user if the Create user if ubique condition Is true and redirects user to Connect otherwise It redirects the users on Amazon Connect directly. I don't Need to store data about the users for my use case.